# Filter array observable by promise

Tags: typescript, filter, rxjs, mergemap

I have

- An array of objects
- A function `permission(obj): Promise<boolean>`

**How can I filter this array by the promise?**

I've tried numerous things, and the closest I got was

```
of(arr).pipe(
  switchMap(items =>
    from(items)
     .pipe(
       mergeMap(item =>
         fromPromise(permission(item)).pipe(
           map(shown => ({show, item})),
           filter(data => data.shown),
           map(data => data.item)
         )
       ))
     ));
```

But that just seems needlessly complicated.

I had hoped I could do it more simple like `of(arr).pipe(filterByPromise(permission))`, but can't seem to figure out how.

I made a Stackblitz https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-g1u8yk

#### StackBlitz code

```
import { of } from 'rxjs'; 
import { map, filter } from 'rxjs/operators';

// Mocked 3rd party function
function visible(obj): Promise<boolean> {
  return new Promise(resolve => {
    const shouldShow = obj.shouldShow < 30;
    resolve(shouldShow);
  });
}

const arr = [{
  shouldShow: 39,
  data1: 'abc',
  data2: 'bcd'
}, {
  shouldShow: 22,
  data1: 'cde',
  data2: 'def'
}];

of(arr).pipe(
  filter(obj => visible(obj))
).subscribe(result => console.log(result));
```

Comment: Your code can be reduced to `from(arr).pipe(
  mergeMap(element => from(visible(element)).pipe(filter(show => show), map(() => element)))
)`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JB Nizet [suggested](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/57336466/filter-array-observable-by-promise/57337088#comment101162253_57336466) nice solution, but it would be better to use `concatMap`, if item order matters. [Here](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/transformation/concatmap.html) the difference between `concatMap` and `mergeMap` is explained.

```js
from(arr).pipe(
  concatMap(element => from(visible(element)).pipe(
    filter(show => show),
    map(() => element)
  ))
).subscribe(console.log);
```

The other way is to transform and [zip](https://www.learnrxjs.io/operators/combination/zip.html) the array, like this. But the solution about is more elegant I think.

```js
zip(...arr.map(obj => from(visible(obj)))).pipe(
  map(visible => arr.filter((item, i) => visible[i]))
).subscribe(console.log);
```

[Here is](https://stackblitz.com/edit/rxjs-zsbyzr) working example of both solutions.